# Creating alerts & Best Practices

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

A bit of background:
We have set up a new grafana install and have AWS Cloudwatch & Prometheus data sources added. I have imported a few dashboards and customised them as we would like.

One of which is this one:
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7587

On the dashboard the monitor I have set up is as follows -
probe_success{instance=~"$target", job="$App"}

our environment consists of various production, staging and test servers (their host names indicate which environment they are part of)

For example:
srv01-staging
srv01-production

I’m trying to create an alert to monitor the HTTP response for ONLY the production servers.

My alert code is as below:
probe_success{job = “nameofjob”}

My issue is that this will alert on ALL failures even on our staging/test environments which I do not want.

I don’t believe we can use variables in alerts - or if we can I havn’t been able to get it working.

TLDR:
What is the best way to segment alerts so that I am not notified of issues with our staging/test environments?

Many Thanks!

---

Answer (score 0):

You can just either trigger only production metrics by explicitly set a label matching production:

`probe_success{job="nameofjob", namespace="production"}` or `probe_success{job="nameofjob", server=~"prod-.*"}` (server and namespace are arbitraty labels. namespace is common in kubernetes environments).

or exclude the environments you don't want such:

`probe_success{job="nameofjob", namespace!~"staging|test"}`

Use whatever label can make a distinction between production and the others. And if you don't have such label, you should add one then.

Some resources that could help you:

- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config
- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/